# ASP.NET MVC4 Unit Of Work with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I am designing a new asp.net MVC4 application. I know that context class generated by EF is a unit of work and `DbSet` is the repository class. So I am just avoiding the extra abstaction. I want to know whether I am following the correct pattern or not.

Sample Code :

**Entities**:

```
  public partial class ProductMaster
  {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

  }

  public partial class CompanyMaster
  {
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
  }
```

**Context** class (generated By EF):

```
public partial class SampleEntities : DbContext,IUnitOfWork
{
    public SampleEntities()
        : base("name=SampleEntities")
    {
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
       SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<ProductMaster> ProductMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyMaster> CompanyMaster { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserMaster> UserMaster{ get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectResult<SP_UserMaster_Result> SP_UserMaster(Nullable<long> tM_UM_ID, string userName, string userPassword, Nullable<byte> userType)
    {
        var tM_UM_IDParameter = tM_UM_ID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("TM_UM_ID", tM_UM_ID) :
            new ObjectParameter("TM_UM_ID", typeof(long));

        var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

        var userPasswordParameter = userPassword != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserPassword", userPassword) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserPassword", typeof(string));

        var userTypeParameter = userType.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserType", userType) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserType", typeof(byte));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<SP_UserMaster_Result>("SP_UserMaster", tM_UM_IDParameter, userNameParameter, userPasswordParameter, userTypeParameter);
    }
}
```

**Unit of Work interface**:

```
public Interface IUnitOfWork
{
    public DbSet<ProductMaster> ProductMaster;
    public DbSet<CompanyMaster> CompanyMaster;
    public Dbset<UserMaster> UserMaster;
    public virtual ObjectResult SP_UserMaster(Nullable<long> tM_UM_ID, string userName, string userPassword, Nullable<byte> userType){};
    public void Commit();
}
```

**Business logic** (implementation):

```
 public class ProductMaster
 {
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ProductMaster(IunitOfWork unitOfWork)//Injected using Ninject
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        _unitofWork.ProductMaster.Add(product);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
 }
```

Interface of product logic:

```
 public class IProductMaster
 {
    public ProductMaster(IunitOfWork unitOfWork);
 }
```

Product controller:

```
  public class ProductController : Controller
  {
     IProductMaster _productMaster;

     public ProductController(IproductMaster productMaster)
     {
        this._ProductMaster=productMaster;//Injecting using Ninject
     }

     public void SaveProduct(Product product)
     {
        this._productMaster.AddProduct(product.ToEntity());
     }
  }
```

Comment: Seems correct to me. Or any special point you would like to draw attention?

Comment: It would be more better if you add a repository pattern to the current pattern.

Comment: Repository is already implemented by the entitiy framework(eg: Dbset). What is the advantage of adding another layer of abstraction over it?

Comment: Testability, replacability (swap EF for another ORM), abstraction (implement multiple equal actions for equal entities only once). This question is off-topic for SO though, try searching http://programmers.stackexchange.com for "why use repository pattern". Also note there is a lot of hate for the repository pattern, especially when using an ORM, while the repository does add value in certain cases.

Comment: If then is there any way to  add the stored procedure functions in the generic repository class so that we can call the same from the logic layer without specifying the query in the logic layer class. I don't want to call the stored procedure in this way  .`var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<yourEntityType>(
    "yourSpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);`